# Solution to $x^2-y^{11}=23$ in positive integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

Are there positive integers that make the following equation true?  $x^2-y^{11}=23$

I do not think it is possible because I have tried many numbers any none of them seem to work. I was able to solve it with an easier case: $x^2 - y^2 = 23$. We can factor to get: $(x+y)(x-y)=23$ Since 23 is prime, its prime factorization is $23 \cdot 1$. We can now solve for $x$ any by doing $(x+y) = 23$ and $(x-y)=1$. $x = 12$, $y = 11$. Although this works for this case, I don't know if it'll work for the original problem.

Comment: This is a hyperelliptic curve of genus $5$. Maybe there is hope by computational methods, like Ratpoint: http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/programs/

Comment: Note that moduloing by $23$ is difficult because for example $22^2-1^{11}=483\equiv 0 \pmod{23}$

Comment: Almost $45^2 - 2^{11}=-23$

Comment: In fact, moduloing by any number $\le 23$ doesn't work

Comment: I have checked numerically that there is no solution under the additional assumption that $y<10000000$

Comment: Why was this question asked again? Was it deleted for some reason? I distinctly remember comments by myself and someone else under this exact same question (initially written as $2x^2-2y^{11}=46$), but they're not here now.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{23}]$ is a PID and we can factor the equation there. This might be helpful

Comment: This is the third time joeken has asked this question in four days. joeken, stop it!

Comment: In the field $\mathbb F_{23}$  we have $x^2=y^{11}$ and always $y^{11}=\pm1$ if $y\ne0$ (because of FLT).The case $y=0$ is easily discarded.  On the other hand $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $23$ because $(-1)^{\frac{23-1}{2}}=-1$. 

It follows that if there is a solution one has $x^2=1+23t$.  Taking now the equations on integer numbers we have impossibilities.

Comment: @Piquito Could you elaborate on how you get an impossibility from this?

Comment: @Wojowu: "....we COULD have impossibilities.". I am not motivated for what you ask me because I am very busy in other things. Regards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose a solution exists. First note that $x$ has to be even. Indeed, if it was odd, then $y^{11}=x^2-23$ would be even but not divisible by $4$ (look mod $4$), which is impossible.

It follows that $y$ has to be odd. But then, since $y^{11}$ is congruent to $y$ modulo $4$ for odd $y$, we find that $y\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Now comes the trick. By adding $y^{11}+2025$ to both sides, we find
$$x^2+45^2=y^{11}+2^{11}=(y+2)(y^{10}-2y^9+2^2y^8\pm\dots+2^{10})=(y+2)A.$$
Observe that A is relatively prime to $y+2$ - we have $A=y^{10}-2y^9+2^2y^8\pm\dots+2^{10}\equiv 11(-2)^{10}\pmod{y+2}$, so since $y+2$ is odd, the only common factor could be $11$, which requires $y\equiv -2\pmod{11}$. But going back to the original equation, this would imply $-1$ is a square modulo $11$, which it certainly isn't.

To sum up, we have established that $y+2$ and $A$ are relatively prime numbers whose product is a sum of two squares. However, we can see that both of them are $3\pmod 4$, so both have prime factors which are $3\pmod 4$. One of those factors must not be equal to $3$, call it $p$. By considering the displayed equation modulo $p$, we find $x^2\equiv -45^2\pmod p$, and since $p\neq 3,5$, by taking multiplicative inverse of $45$ modulo $p$ we find $z^2\equiv -1\pmod p$ has an integer solution. However, it is well-known that this is impossible whenever $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$. This gives a contradiction, showing that the equation has no solution.

(Proof inspired by the proof of Theorem 2.1 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf).)

Comment: Exhibition of ingenuity!!!!